# Regex: Count How Many Single-Character Words Are In a String

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use RegEx to count how many single-character words are in a given string?

This string has one: "a hello" 
This string has two: "a b hello"

and so on.

I am not interested as much in the count itself as I am in discarding the patterns with more than one single-character word. In the above example, the second string would be discarded.

Comment: You could perform 2 replace operations, first replacing all 2+ character words then all whitespace. If string is 2+ chars in length, discard.

Comment: What language you use? Show your attempts.

Comment: this is very easy in C without using regex.

Comment: I generally use Python and JS, but am somewhat spotty on RegEx. Hence, I was looking for some direction.

Comment: `Is it possible to use RegEx to count how many single-character words are in a given string?` No it's not. It's impossible to parse natural language words with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Regex, this is how I would do it in Ruby:

`/\b\w\b/`

```
\b = word boundary (zero-length assertion)
\w = word character (letter, number, underscore)
```

Comment: Very cool! So, if I use string.match() in Javascript, this would return false on strings with more than one single-character words?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The opposite. true on strings with at least one single-character word

Comment: `{1}` is the same as no quantifier at all.  It's just clutter.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to include the case where there are no single character words or only one. Would I modify the regex to be:` /\b\w\b{0-1}/` ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist not exactly. When you match on a Regex, it returns the parts of the string that match, not just true or false. So you would then count the number of matches in what was returned. Using {0-1} in the Regex isn't going to help you with that.  You should take a look at Matt's answer; it looks like it would accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you saying that an if-statement would be needed?

Comment: Yes, it would look like Matt's answer.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on jktin's answer,

```
function checkString(string) {
  if (string.match(/\b\w{1}\b/g).length > 1){
    discardString();
  }
  keepString();
}
```

Of course, discardString and keepString are whatever you want them to be.

Comment: I think I shall use Python in this case but thank you anyways. By the way, the "g" that follows the RegEx is Javascript-specific, is it not?

Comment: I think so; you'd have to use findall from what I can gather. I don't know python yet :)